# how to get mailbox quota statistics using MailKit?

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit

I'm using Mailkit IMAP client to connect to mail server but I receive errors when trying to get mailbox quota, can anyone help?

```
            var root = client.GetFolder(client.PersonalNamespaces[0]);
            root.Open(MailKit.FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
            return root.GetQuota();
```

the error message is

> The IMAP server replied to the 'EXAMINE' command with a 'BAD' response

the mail server I use is kolab mail server.

What I want to do is to find out the mailbox storage usage of each user.

Any hekp highly appreciated!  thanks.

Comment: It seems it doesn't like you doing it readonly. Take that part out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to open the root folder to get the quota.

Most IMAP servers have a folder root that is not an actual folder and thus you will not be able to open it (just like in your case).